Airline added services: cooling-off law?
Are airline’s added services (such as additional luggage allowance) purchased in addition to an exisiting airline ticket subject to the colling-off law in the US?

What "cooling-off law" do you have in mind?  Are you thinking of the rule that tickets can be cancelled for a full refund within 24 hours of purchase?

No.
The cooling off period you're referring to is mandated by the 14 CFR 259.5(b)(4), and refers specifically to reservations:

Allowing reservations to be held at the quoted fare without payment, or cancelled without penalty, for at least twenty-four hours after the reservation is made if the reservation is made one week or more prior to a flight's departure, and disclosing its chosen twenty-four hour policy on the last page of the booking process;

There are different rules for refunds of the ancillary fees governed by the 14 CFR 260. These boil down to refund being required if the service was not provided due to the airlines' fault.
